# Google Maps - Offcenter Map on Result

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have a listener that pops open a div whenever a marker is clicked:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    var boxText = document.createElement("div");
    boxText.style.cssText = "margin-top: 8px; background: #fff; padding: 0px;";
    boxText.innerHTML = this.html;

    infoBox.setContent(boxText);
    infoBox.open(map, this);

    // Set Box Location
    infoBox.pixelOffset_.height = searchType == "Event" ? -323 : -266;

    // Set Map Center
    map.panTo(infoBox.getPosition());
});
```

With regards to the last line: `map.panTo(infoBox.getPosition())`, is there a way to offcenter this, so that the map actually centers above the result? My infoBox is getting cut off by my header. I don't want to offset by actual coordinates, but rather just about a hundred pixels or so.

I've tried adding this below it: `map.panBy(0, 100)` but it doesn't work. I can change the first number to move left or right, but the second number has no effect.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle or some other working example?

Comment: Would it work to look at it from my live version? http://www.otherlane.com/discover?event_search=&event_filter=&event_timeselect=This%20Week&event_start_date=&event_end_date=&event_kid_friendly=False&event_no_underage=False&event_free_admission=False&event_after_five=False&event_location=POINT(-75.15745670000001%2039.9509036)&search_type=Event

Comment: It help to understand the problem, but not much to find a solution :) I prefer to play with jsfiddle... much easier

Comment: I ended up figuring it out. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

I added this line below.

`map.panBy(0, -200)`

It wasn't working earlier, but I guess I fiddled with it long enough. This ended up being the solution.